how can I insert data to my db inside the handle() on my job?
I have a job on my laravel project that makes a request to an API and I want to insert the response from this request on my database, every part of my code is working but the data is not being inserted.
on my job I have the following:
public function __construct($dados, WgClient $model)
    {
        $this->dados = $dados;
        $this->model = $model;        
    }

public function handle()
    {
        try {
            $dataWG = [
                'tipo' => 'interface',
                'data' => $this->data
            ];
            
            $response = Http::post('http://my.api.ip.address:port/login', [  
                'username' => '*',
                'password' => '*',
            ]);
    
    
            if (!isset($response->json()['access_token'])) 
                    throw new Exception("Erro na autenticação");
    
            $token = $response->json()['access_token'];

            $response = Http::withHeaders([
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
            ])->post('http://my.api.ip.address:port/criar', $dataWG);

            $response = json_decode($response, true);

            $this->model->name = $response['name'];
            $this->model->network = $response['network'];
            $this->model->public_key = $response['public_key'];
            $this->model->private_key = $response['private_key'];
            $this->model->port = $response['port'];
            $this->model->company = 13;
            $this->model->save();

        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            throw $th;
        }
    }

I'm calling the dispatch like this:
$data = $request->all();
$model = new WgClient;
CreateWgInterfaceJob::dispatch($data, $model);

I'm using redis and horizon, here are the configs for redis on my queue.php:
'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => null,
            'after_commit' => false,
        ],

this is my supervisor configs on my horizon.php:
'defaults' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['default'],
            'balance' => 'simple',
            'autoScalingStrategy' => 'time',
            'maxProcesses' => 1,
            'maxTime' => 0,
            'maxJobs' => 0,
            'memory' => 128,
            'tries' => 1,
            'timeout' => 60,
            'nice' => 0,
        ],
    ],

one important thing to note is that my project is inside docker, so I have a container for my laravel project, a container for my database, a container for redis and another one for horizon, I've tried running php artisan queue:work both inside my main laravel container and inside my horizon container but the data still won't persist in the database, here is my docker compose for reference:
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    container_name: 'mysql_accessmanager'
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    env_file:
      - ./config/db.env
    volumes:
      - ./config/CreateDBs.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.sql
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - netaccessmanager

  accessmanager:
    container_name: 'accessmanager'
    image: docker.io/bitnami/laravel:9
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 4727:8000
    env_file:
      - ./config/laravel.env  
    environment:
      - DB_DATABASE=db_accessmanager
    volumes:
      - ./laravel/accessmanager:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - netaccessmanager
  
  fila_accessmanager:
    container_name: 'fila_accessmanager'
    image: docker.io/bitnami/laravel:9
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./config/laravel.env  
    environment:
      - DB_DATABASE=db_accessmanager
    volumes:
      - ./laravel/accessmanager:/app
    entrypoint: ["bash", "-c", "php artisan horizon"]
    depends_on:
      - accessmanager
    networks:
      - netaccessmanager

  agenda_accessmanager:
    container_name: 'agenda_accessmanager'
    image: docker.io/bitnami/laravel:9
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./config/laravel.env  
    environment:
      - DB_DATABASE=db_accessmanager
    volumes:
      - /mnt/efs-data/docker/accessmanager/laravel/accessmanager:/app
    entrypoint: ["bash", "-c", "php artisan schedule:work"]
    depends_on:
      - accessmanager
    networks:
      - netaccessmanager

  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: 'phpmyadmin_accessmanager'
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./config/phpmyadmin.env
    ports:
      - "1004:80"
    networks:
      - netaccessmanager

  redis:
    container_name: 'redis_accessmanager'
    image: redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - ./redis:/data
    networks:
      - netaccessmanager

networks:
    netaccessmanager:

As per suggestion from @Abolfazl I tried putting only Log::info() in the handle method and at first it didn't work but after running queue:work it started logging correctly.
I've tried both the answers from here and here but they didn't work and I don't really understand why, I also tried with and without SerializesModels and I get the same result, everything works but nothing goes to the database and there's no errors to be seen, I know I'm missing something so some help and explanation would be highly appreciated.

How are you processing the queue? Do you have a worker?

Just for checking, delete all try catch blocks and put only a Log::info() into handle and check if it works? If not I can say it's related to running the worker.

If using redis, get your hands on telescope and horizon. There doesn't seem to be a worker processing the queue. You're supervisor config for the redis part would be useful, same for the config setup on queues.

Sorry for the late response, I tried your suggestion @AbolfazlB and even with only the Log::info() the handle method didn't work but after the php artisan queue:work it started logging normally again, also I am using horizon and now I have confirmed that I have workers running, I will edit the original post to provide more information (sorry about not including in the first place)
